# Using ajax to send a Proto-buf message to a Java server

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, protocol-buffers, arraybuffer

Using https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/ I encoded a message I want to send to a java server to a ByteBuffer called batch:

```
batch:
  ByteBuffer {array: ArrayBuffer, view: DataView, offset: 0, markedOffset: -1, length: 139…}
    array: ArrayBuffer
    length: 139
    littleEndian: false
    markedOffset: -1
    offset: 0
    view: DataView
    __proto__: Object
```

Now I want to send this with jquery's Ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    data : batch,
    contentType: 'application/protobuf',
    accept: 'application/json'
  })
```

But I can't seem to do this. The above code gives me the jquery exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'littleEndian' of undefined myScript.js:1353
ByteBuffer.LE bunk.js:1353
jQuery.param.add jquery.js:7203
buildParams jquery.js:7261
jQuery.param jquery.js:7223
jQuery.extend.ajax
```

If I get an array buffer from batch (batch.toArrayBuffer()) the Java server gets nothing from

```
ByteStreams.toByteArray(req.getInputStream());
```

How should I encode the ByteBuffer to send like this? And how should I decode it into a java byte array?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm setting the contentType to application/x-protobuf and the object on the java side is not null but does not have the sent values. ideas?

Comment: ProtoBuf.js uses the original protobuf protocol, which is meant to be sent over a binary protocol (like websockets), which is why the data is stored using "ByteBuffer".  What you are looking for sounds more like "PBLite", which is Google's JS data-like brand of protobuf (which is sent as a indexed JS array).

Comment: If you are interested in pblite: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/git-history/docs/namespace_goog_proto2.html
A few people here and there developed some pblite tools

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you found a solution but Google Protocol Buffers now come with a javascript compiler.

Once you have built your object to send with the proto builder, You can send data using jQuery using the following:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "http://localhost:8088/user",
        data: user.serializeBinary(),
        success: function () {
            $("#message").text("User with key " + user.getApikey() + " saved");
        },
        contentType: "application/x-protobuf",
        processData: false
    });
```

ProcessData: false is **necessary** to avoid jQuery serialising the data in the background.

Comment: Protobuf3 comes with JS output

Answer (score 0):

From JQuery's documentation on ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> Note: The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change the encoding.

You're probably trying to send raw binary bytes from your protobuffer, which is not compatible with UTF-8.

I'm not familiar with ProtoBuf.js, but from a little digging online it looks like there's a toBase64() method available for encoding the protobuf as a base64 string. Try using that method to get the data to send, and then on the server decode from base64.

Comment: Doesn't that sort of defeat the purpose if you have to intermediately encode it as Base64